# Store / read binary files: which is the most performant approach?

Tags: database, binaryfiles, file-storage

I know SQL or NoSQL questions have been asked and discussed over and over again.

I have a very specific case on which I want to decide upon one or the other way.

I need to store documents and retrieve them in an efficient way. The structure / flexibility of the structure is not an issue here - only the storage and more importantly, the reading of the binary file itself.

Is one or the other method a preferred choice for the specific use-case and, if so, could someone explain why?

**UPDATE**
I realize the question is improperly formulated. The question is not related to structure, so SQL vs NoSQL isn't the right topic here. Apologies.
Say I want to create a database as a file storage. As said, storing absolute file paths isn't an option here. The question is whether there is a known DB server optimized for that.

Comment: Can you provide some specifics? What is the nature of the architecture? Are the files large, small, all different sizes, etc.? Typically, one stores files in a file system, which is *the original* nosql database.

Comment: please look at my update...

Comment: So, as far as I can tell, your question is "I need to store documents and retrieve them in an efficient way." This question lacks any context that would be required to provide you with a meaningful answer. What are your requirements? How "efficient" does it need to be? What are the constraints of your system? Why can't you simply use the file system of the computer you are using? It's impossible to understand your question without additional context.

Answer (score 0):

SQL and NoSQL differ in how they structure and query the data.

However, *binary* files to not have any structure, and are written and queried as a single blob.
Therefore, the differences between SQL and NoSQL do not matter.

In other words, there might be big differences how *specific* databases handle blobs, but those differences would not be related to whether a DB uses SQL or not.

(But it should be noted that there are certain NoSQL databases that are particularly optimized for storing binary files; they are called "file systems".)